# Get contingency table for each column of a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, count, contingency

Suppose I have a matrix of numbers.  The matrix has `dim(X)=(200,5)` and each element is between 1 and 5.

I'd like to know the count of each number in each column.  Something that looks like

```
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1 #  #  #  #  #
2 #  #  #  #  #
3 #  #  #  #  #
4 #  #  #  #  #
5 #  #  #  #  #
```

The sum of each column should be 200 since there are 200 rows.

`table` seemed promising, but it only returns the counts for the entire matrix, not the columns.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: @Gregor sorry, I meant the count in that bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this for something in general. For example

- when you have a matrix of letters;
- when you still have a matrix of integer but they are not contiguous, say, 5, 7, 10, 11, 20.

--

```
cX <- c(X)
k <- sort(unique(cX))
## as if we have a matrix of factors
XX <- matrix(match(cX, k), dim(X)[1], dimnames = list(k, 1:dim(X)[2]))
## aligned column-wise contingency table
tab <- apply(XX, 2, tabulate)
## aligned column-wise proportion table
prop <- tab / colSums(tab)[col(tab)]
```

---

I have abandoned my initial answer

```
lapply(data.frame(X), table)
apply(X, 2, table)
```

or  the second version (a more robust one, but as inefficient as the first solution):

```
k <- sort(unique(c(X)))
apply(X, 2, function (u) table(factor(u, levels = k)) )
```

The new answer above is kind of "overkill" for your example, but is more useful in practice (I think).

Comment: Worked, but `sapply` would have given me exactly what I wanted.  Thanks!

Comment: @DemetriP Careful making assumptions about `sapply` - it will only be able to simplify if every number is present in every column. If some columns don't have every value you will end up with a `list` like `lapply`.

Comment: @李哲源ZheyuanLi No.  Thanks, I've accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about `tabulate` in base R:

```
apply(m,2,tabulate)

#    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]   39   47   38   42   34
#[2,]   41   43   41   36   39
#[3,]   46   33   38   44   39
#[4,]   35   31   40   41   53
#[5,]   39   46   43   37   35
```

OR `table`:

```
apply(m,2,table)
```

**data**

```
set.seed(1)
m <- t(replicate(200,sample(5),))
```